# InfluxDB JSON response formatting

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a JSON response from influxdb http query as below:

```
{
    "results": [{
        "statement_id": 0,
        "series": [{
            "name": "healthCheckTestV1",
            "columns": ["time", "transactionName", "responseTime"],
            "values": [
                ["2018-11-20T08:09:50.4799222Z", "Security_Question", 4.167099],
                ["2018-11-20T08:09:50.0868723Z", "File_Download", 4.867642],
                ["2018-11-20T08:09:49.6968331Z", "View_File", 9.709544],
                ["2018-11-20T08:09:49.3077855Z", "Open_TEAM", 18.121819],
                ["2018-11-20T08:09:48.9147399Z", "File_Upload", 9.891604],
                ["2018-11-20T08:09:47.0675403Z", "Open_OneDrive", 2.793456],
                ["2018-11-20T08:09:46.5719031Z", "Logout", 11.781315],
                ["2018-11-20T08:08:06.0374685Z", "Login_OKTA", 7.293168],
                ["2018-11-20T08:07:49.8022407Z", "HomePage", 3.037265]
            ]
        }]
    }]
}
```

I want to display the above content in the below format in JavaScript.

```
 File_Download   9
 View_File       8
 Open_TEAM       7
 Open_OneDrive   6
 File_Upload     5
 File_Download   4
```

I am completely new to JavaScript/json. Appreciate someone could help me. Many Thanks

#### My attempt:

```js
var response = getResponse();
for (var i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
  for (var t = 0; t < response.results[i].series.length; t++) {
    console.log(response.results[i].series[t].columns);
    console.log("**********************************************");
    for (var j = 0; j < response.results[i].series[t].values.length; j++) {
      console.log(response.results[i].series[t].values[j])
    }
  }
}

function getResponse() {
  return {
    "results": [{
      "statement_id": 0,
      "series": [{
        "name": "healthCheckTestV1",
        "columns": ["time", "transactionName", "responseTime"],
        "values": [
          ["2018-11-20T08:09:50.4799222Z", "Security_Question", 4.167099],
          ["2018-11-20T08:09:50.0868723Z", "File_Download", 4.867642],
          ["2018-11-20T08:09:49.6968331Z", "View_File", 9.709544],
          ["2018-11-20T08:09:49.3077855Z", "Open_TEAM", 18.121819],
          ["2018-11-20T08:09:48.9147399Z", "File_Upload", 9.891604],
          ["2018-11-20T08:09:47.0675403Z", "Open_OneDrive", 2.793456],
          ["2018-11-20T08:09:46.5719031Z", "Logout", 11.781315],
          ["2018-11-20T08:08:06.0374685Z", "Login_OKTA", 7.293168],
          ["2018-11-20T08:07:49.8022407Z", "HomePage", 3.037265]
        ]
      }]
    }]
  };
}
```

The output comes as below:

```
[ 'time', 'transactionName', 'responseTime' ]
**********************************************
[ '2018-11-20T09:16:15.1442021Z', 'Security_Question', 3.750389 ]
[ '2018-11-20T09:16:14.7631577Z', 'File_Download', 5.369951 ]
[ '2018-11-20T09:16:13.9440692Z', 'View_File', 13.827224 ]
[ '2018-11-20T09:16:13.3379987Z', 'Open_TEAM', 17.779691 ]
[ '2018-11-20T09:16:12.9609559Z', 'File_Upload', 38.956707 ]
[ '2018-11-20T09:16:12.5737327Z', 'Open_OneDrive', 2.949066 ]
[ '2018-11-20T09:16:12.0929475Z', 'Logout', 11.773299 ]
[ '2018-11-20T09:13:50.9144754Z','Login_OKTA',6.6948170000000005 ]
[ '2018-11-20T09:13:36.2807192Z', 'HomePage', 2.719711 ]
```

Comment: Have you tried accesing data in this response? How are these numbers in expected output related to your dataset?

Comment: sorry its just an example of the output. Ideally it should be with decimals

Comment: I've replaced in your code that part where you parsed JSON with your object (now it's working snippet and other users can easily modify it) and added back subject of this question. IMO [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) may help you. Is it ok for you to log it (into console) or are you going to display it using html?

Comment: @Barbsan - thanks. I need to return it as string variable. As next step I need to hook this code into AWS lambda and then integrate with AWS LEX.

Comment: Well, it seems that your goal is quite different than the one you posted in question - there's some table-like content you want to display, now it's string variable. Do you know what should be in content of this string variable? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve and this question may become too broad soon. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)